# xcode 5, I would like to remove a class in uiWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm creating an iPhone app which loads various web views. I have figured out how to remove a 'header' div in the below code however the same approach is not working for the class 'main-sections'. Can anyone advise how to target and display:none this class in Xcode?

Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
_webView.delegate=nil;
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"header\").style.display=\"none\";"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName(\"main-sections\").style.display=\"none\";"];

}
```

Comment: first of all document.getElementsByClassName returns an Array, so you have to do it in a for loop. And second, the code to hide header is correct, if it is not working this might be because you do not have an element with id "header"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get element by class name is an array so like this.

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName(\"main-sections\")[0].style.display=\"none\";"];
```

Or if you wish to apply it to all elements with that class

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"
var arrayData = document.getElementsByClassName(\"main-sections\");
for (item in arrayData) {
item.style.display=\"none\";
}
"];
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response, this has worked perfectly!

Comment: This is not working for me. i have written this in webviewdidfinish